# How to make an alias for git add *name*?

Tags: git

I'm trying to create an alias for `git add *name*`, so I could use it like this:

```
git a foo
```

And it would call the following:

```
git add *foo*
```

How can I do it? I tried `a = add *$1*`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just alias add, any additional parameters will be passed through.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please mind those automatically added asterisks.

Comment: Oh I assumed they were to indicate that's the thing you wanted, not part of the branch name. Why do you want that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for shell variables (`$1`) to be evaluated in a git alias, it needs to be a shell git alias, instead of a built-in alias. These are aliases prefixed with a `!`.

```
git config alias.a '!sh -c "git add  *$1*"'
```

will do the trick. You could also directly add the line to your git config as follows:

```
[alias]
    a = !sh -c \"git add *$1*\"
```

However, if you want to support specifying multiple files, you'll need to make something more intricate, like a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#file: $HOME/bin/git-a
newargs=()
for arg in "$@"; do
    newargs+=("*$arg*")
done
git add "${newargs[@]}"
```

Then make sure it's executable and in your `$PATH`. If it is, then git will find it and execute it when you type `git a`, without having to set up an alias.

Adding additional features, like passing through other flags to git add, is left as an exercise to you.

Comment: That's it, thank you. I found out that generated syntax is: `a = !sh -c \"git add *$1*\"`. Please add it to your answer for future reference. Many people prefer to use .gitconfig file instead of adding config through console.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your home directory, look for a file called `.gitconfig`, and add the following:

```
[alias]:
    a = add
```

UPDATE:

create this file (`gitadd.sh`)

```
gitadd() {
    for ARG in "$@"
    do
        git add "./*$ARG*"
    done
}
```

usage:

- add gitadd function to `~/.bash_aliases`
- reload it to take effect using `source ~/.bashrc`
- use it like this: `gitadd name`

Comment: Please notice those asterisks that I want to add automatically. That's my entire point.

Comment: Can that be done in alias section? And without the loop?

Comment: mm I don't know, this is a different approach

Comment: It was `a = !sh -c \"git add *$1*\"` :)